# How do I install Lazarus in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install lazarus-1.6.4-fpc-3.0.2 34/64 bit on Ubuntu 17.04? I have previously installed Lazarus without problems on Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier versions; but, installation fails with Ubuntu 17.04. Something changed.
Help greatly appreciated.

More Details:

1. Downloaded the three DEB Lazarus from https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.6.4/
2. Saved to Downloads directory.
3. Double clicked on first file. The file was set to open with "Ubuntu Software".
4. A window opens with an "install" button.
5. Clicked on the "install" button.
6. Nothing happens, no errors shown, no authorization dialog box.
7. Tried the other two files, same result; nothing!!

With earlier versions of Ubuntu, Lazarus was successfully installed using the "Ubuntu Software" application. However; with Ubuntu 17.04, the same "Ubuntu Software" install application does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on how you used to install Lazarus, and exact details on the failure.

Comment: Download the `.deb` file from [here](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) and install it. if you're having trouble installing `.deb` files mention that in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `libgtk2-dev` is installed, and then open a terminal. Use `cd` to go to where you downloaded the 3 files and install them using this command:

```
dpkg -i fpc_3.0.2-170225_amd64.deb fpc-src_3.0.2-170225_amd64.deb fpc_3.0.2-170225_amd64.deb
```

This method worked for me in Ubuntu 17.04.